# Wordpress display name string manipulation

Tags: php, string, wordpress, function

I have set the display name to show both first name and last name using the function below. How do I manipulate the LAST NAME to only pull the first letter of that string? Example, if you sign up as John Doe (First name= John, Last name= Doe), I want your display name to be John D.

Thanks

```
function force_pretty_displaynames($user_login, $user) {

$outcome = trim(get_user_meta($user->ID, 'first_name', true) . " " . get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_name', true));
if (!empty($outcome) && ($user->data->display_name!=$outcome)) {
    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user->ID, 'display_name' => $outcome));    
}
}
add_action('wp_login','force_pretty_displaynames',10,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get first char from `get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_name', true)`. You can use string as array of chars (because it's array of chars :) ) so to get first char you will write `$string[0]`.

```
$lastName = (string) get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_name', true);
$firstChar = $lastName[0];
```

Comment: Elon can you please clarify by inserting your answer into my code? When I tried it, I got Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_User as array. Thanks!

Comment: Edited answer, I think it'll be easy now to use that solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it Using PHP's substr() function:

```
  $outcome = trim(
get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'first_name', true ) 
. ' ' 
. substr( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_name', true ), 0, 1 )
. '.'
);
```

Above code thanks to Pat J

Full code to display FIRST NAME and Initial of LAST NAME in wordpress is below. If anyone else wants to use it, remember to paste it in your theme's function.php file

```
function force_pretty_displaynames($user_login, $user) {

$outcome = trim(
get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'first_name', true ) 
. ' ' 
. substr( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_name', true ), 0, 1 )
. '.'
);
if (!empty($outcome) && ($user->data->display_name!=$outcome)) {
    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user->ID, 'display_name' => $outcome));    
}
}
add_action('wp_login','force_pretty_displaynames',10,2);
```